# How to remove Advertise banner from skype version 6.22.81?

Tags: skype

I have updated the Skype to latest version that is Skype 6.22.81.
I have already tried to option of control panel -> Internet Option -> blocked URL.

That is not disabling advertisement on Skype.
waiting for prompt and quick response.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this link

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-ads-in-skype/

It not only remove the ad but it removes the whole bar.

Overview of the steps listed in the link

1. Add https://apps.skype.com in restricted sites
2. Open config file of skype. You can find the config.xml in directory similar to the below example
   C:\users[your user name]\App Data\Roaming\Skype[your Skype username]
   **Example** C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Skype\live#3aadmin101
3. Search for AdvertPlaceholder tag and remove the line
4. Then make the config.xml readonly to restrict skype from adding it automatically again.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I created a Windows Batch script to help remove the ADS from Skype, it can add a blacklist to Windows hosts file and also change a parameter on the Skype user settings file.

This way I was able to remove all ADS from Skype 7, including the ADS block that appears on the right side of the chat.

This script was tested on Skype 7.85.105.101 and is intended to run on Windows Vista, 7 or 8.

You can get the script here: [disable_skype_ads.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/re10fb46yu5vi00/disable_skype_ads.zip).
Unpack the zip and read the readme.txt file to know how to use it.

If you find any bugs or have suggestions, please add a comment bellow, so I can fix/improve it.